# How to Use .as Exported File from PhysicsEditor

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, nape

The question was here for a long time with bounty and no satisfying solution for me. I erased the first post and am posting instead a question that can be answered quickly with a yes or no so I can proceed with my doings.

If you could answer it really fast before it's deleted by "not a good question". Is using a custom shape from PhysicsEditor to Nape the same as doing it with [Box2D](https://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2011/05/13/tutorial-create-collision-shapes-for-box2d-flash-as3)? (ofc changing syntax)

If you could then give a look in that link then say it's the same process in Nape that'll be enought thanks.

I ask this because I found the Box2D tutorial easier to follow so far.

```
public var floor:Body;

floor = new Body(BodyType.STATIC);
var floorShape:PhysicsData = new PhysicsData();
floor.shapes.add(floorShape); // Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type PhysicsData to an unrelated type nape.shape:Shape.
floor.space = space;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

According to a comment on this [blog post](http://blog.onebyonedesign.com/actionscript/starling-nape-physics-and-physicseditor/), it sounds like recent versions of Nape have broken compatibility with the physics editor. Specifically, the `graphic` and `graphicUpdate` properties no longer exist on body objects. The solution suggested is to remove references to those properties.

I'm not in a position to be able to test this, but you could try updating the `createBody` method of your floor class as follows:

```
public static function createBody(name:String /*,graphic:DisplayObject=null*/):Body {
    var xret:BodyPair = lookup(name);
    //if(graphic==null) return xret.body.copy();

    var ret:Body = xret.body.copy();
    //graphic.x = graphic.y = 0;
    //graphic.rotation = 0;
    //var bounds:Rectangle = graphic.getBounds(graphic);
    //var offset:Vec2 = Vec2.get(bounds.x-xret.anchor.x, bounds.y-xret.anchor.y);

    //ret.graphic = graphic;
    /*
    ret.graphicUpdate = function(b:Body):void {
        var gp:Vec2 = b.localToWorld(offset);
        graphic.x = gp.x;
        graphic.y = gp.y;
        graphic.rotation = (b.rotation*180/Math.PI)%360;
    }   
    */
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I have all that, main class, nape space. I didn't know how to implement the physics generated code into it. Going to look at your sample thx

Comment: I'm guessing a bit here, but you should just be able to add it TO a body or AS a body in your nape space. Why not post a stripped down version of the class in your question?

Comment: Hadn't seen you updated the post... Thought I'd get a warning on top of the page for that aswell. All I saw last days was "Your bounty on the question [...] expires in x days". Going to check it out thx

Comment: Sooo, cleared all 15 errors, one left: _Implicit coercion of a value of type PhysicsData to an unrelated type nape.shape:Shape_ -- In the line `floor.shapes.add(floorShape);`

Comment: Most of the errors were fixed when I changed `s.cbType = cbType;` to `s.cbTypes.add(cbType);` 5 others were related to the graphics thingy as you pointed out

Comment: No, there's still the _Implicit coercion of a value of type PhysicsData to an unrelated type nape.shape:Shape_ in the line `floor.shapes.add(floorShape);`